# Node id in views template

Tags: views, nodes

Sorry if this question has been answered already but I couldn't find an exact answer. Maybe I'm missing something.

Context of my issue:

I have a view that lists fields of certain content type. One of the fields is the nid. I need to do some validation in the view template before printing anything. So I need to call a function and check something using the nid as parameter. In my views-view-fields.tpl.php I do something like:

```
<?php foreach ($fields as $id => $field): ?>
    <?php if ($id == "nid"): ?>  
        <?php my_function_here($field->content); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

As you might expect, $field->content is a string and if I do something like this in my function, it just won't work.

```
function my_function_here($nid) {
    var_dump(node_load($nid));
}
```

I tried casting the value to integer, but still no luck (casting returns 0):

```
function my_function_here($nid) {
    $nid = (int)$nid;
    var_dump(node_load($nid));
}
```

and

```
function my_function_here($nid) {
    $nid = intval($nid);
    var_dump(node_load($nid));
}
```

So my question is: how do I get the nid in that view template?

Big thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a similar issue - you can find details [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/303586) (or just search for views preprocessor):

A preprocessor will give you access to the data, instead of rendered html which you find in the tpl file.

> There aren't dynamically generated preprocess functions; instead, all
>   of the theme functions use the base preprocessor automatically. So
>   views-view--my-first-view.tpl.php still uses
>   template_preprocess_views_view(&$vars) as its preprocessor function.
>
> You can add preprocess functions for specific views with the exact
>   same naming conventions. Note that that it's named **preprocess* not
>   preprocessor_.
>
> Note that currently Drupal's design requires that you have the
>   .tpl.php file in order to have the preprocess function (though you
>   could drop in a generic preprocess function and do switches based upon
>   information contained within the $vars['view'] variable. There's an
>   issue for this which is fairly easily found by going to the Drupal
>   queue and searching in the 'theme system' queue.